# VBA ошибка при вызове библиотечной функции

Tags: delphi, vba, dll

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые эксперты. У меня очередная проблема, в которой я надеюсь, вы поможете разобраться. Проблема такова: есть простенький класс (Delphi), конструктор класса зашит в динамическую библиотеку

```
type TSome = class
private
    fa, fb, fc:real;
published
    constructor Create(a,b,c:real);
end;

implementation

constructor TSome.Create(a,b,c:real);
begin
    fa:=a;
    fb:=b;
    fc:=c;
end;

теперь создается dll в которой есть экспортная функция с конструктором

library kindll;
uses
    SysUtils,
    Classes,
    kin;//это модуль с классом
    var Some:TSome;
    {$R *.res}

function InitSome(a,b,c:real):TSome;stdcall;
begin
    Some:=TSome.Create(a,b,c);
    result:=Some;
end;

exports InitSome;

begin
end.
```

и теперь функцию из библиотеки нужно заюзать из под VBA. Я попытался сделать это так:

```
Option Explicit
Declare Function InitSome Lib "kindll.dll" _
(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double, ByVal c As Double) As Object

Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
    Dim kp As Object
    Set kp = InitSome(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Что вызвало негодование в виде Память не может быть Read. Подскажите плиз что я не так делаю.

**Добавлено.**

Переписал:

```
type   
PSome=^TSome;   
TSome=class  
.............  
function InitSome(a,b,c:real):PSome;stdcall;   
begin   
    Some:=TSome.Create(a,b,c);   
    result^:=Some;   
end;
```

Все равно при вызове из под VBA бьет ошибку, но уже Память не может быть Written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в Dll используйте класс то работать с ним желательно через интерфейсы или сделать сом

Comment: Судя по всему, Вы правы. Это утверждение повторено было еще на нескольких ресурсах.

Comment: Вот довольно таки хорошая статья на эту тему интерфейсов

http://www.webdelphi.ru/2010/05/realizaciya-interfejsov-intererface-v-delphi/

Вся проблема в том что VBA и Delphi используют различные менеджеры памяти и без интерфейса, даже если удастся заставить работать всеравно вероятность сбоев будет очень высокая.
Ну а самый надежный способ совмешения разных сред програмирования пока-что только СОМ , ну еше можно ActveX попробовать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте работать не с самим обьектом, а с ссылкой на него.

Т.е в dll сделайте функцию:
function InitSome2(a,b,c:real):**PSome**;stdcall;

соответственно класс будет выглядеть так:

```
type 
  PSome = ^TSome;
TSome = class
private
    fa, fb, fc:real;
published
    constructor Create(a,b,c:real);
end;
```

....

Comment: переписал:
type 
PSome=^TSome; 
TSome=class
.............  
function InitSome(a,b,c:real):PSome;stdcall; 
begin 
    Some:=TSome.Create(a,b,c); 
    result^:=Some; 
end;

все равно при вызове из под VBA бьет ошибку, но уже Память не может быть Written 
а за совет спасибо ) буду работать дальше в этом направлении

Answer (score 0):

А ссылку кто инициализировать будет?

```
...
Some:=TSome.Create(a,b,c);  
new(result);
result^:=Some;
...
```

Comment: Этот недочет я уже заметил и исправил, ошибка никуда не делась, только если до этого обращение было к непустому адресу, то сейчас   Инструкция по адресу 0х00000000 обратилась к памяти по адресу 0х00000000.